# Bean inside one Controller Method

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I need a spring managed bean in one of my controller methods. Since I don't need it in any other method, I think it's unnecessary to autowire it. I already read that it should be avoided to use `ApplicationContext.getBean()`, but is there an alternative?

If using `getBean()` is the correct decision, I should mention the created bean has autowired attributes and it seems that they don't get set when creating it with `getBeans()`.

**Code**

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/controller*")
public class Controller {

    @RequestMapping
    public String get(Model model){
        Task task = ApplicationContextHolder.getBean("Task");
        task.getA();

        return "index";
    }
}

public class Task {
    @Autowired(required=true)
    private Service service;

    public List<Object> getA() {
        List<Object> list = service.findWhatever(); //service is null
        return list;
    }
}
```

It's entirely possible I don't understand all the concepts right or I'm missing something. What's the best way to create the `Task` bean?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the `Task` instance is managed by Spring, then you really should inject it. Doing

```
Task task = ApplicationContextHolder.getBean("Task");
```

goes through a whole stack of method calls to try to get the bean. Just `@Autowired` it, you won't have any headaches.

Note that

```
@Autowired(required=true)
private Service service;
```

expects another `Service` bean in the Application context.